# Is there a standard vernacular for levels of political boundaries (specifically city, county, state, nation)

Tags: data, maps, internationalization, boundaries, county

While building a geotemporal web app, I found that virtually all countries followed this simple **four-level structure**, akin to what we in the US of A call: city, county, state, nation.

However, most other nations use different terms for **city, county, state, and nation**.

Is there an "ISO" or similar standard for these names that would be recognized and accepted internationally? (hopefully globally)

Comment: I think it’s worth researching this one at the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 2):

ISO currently doesn't standardize the hierarchical structure of administrative/statistical units. But, there is an EU directive called INSPIRE that specifies data models for 34 data themes in order to support harmonization of data on an EU level.

https://inspire.ec.europa.eu/Themes/114/2892

https://inspire.ec.europa.eu/Themes/125/2892

I know that it wouldn't apply outside of Europe, but you could use some of the concepts, perhaps. Generally, you can define level for each unit and this is a reference. A name of the level could be in English, Spanish or whatever language. The similar concept is applied for Statistical units.

Also, there is a global dataset of administrative regions that follows similar concept (https://gadm.org/)

[image: INSPIRE administrative units UML class diagram]